# How do I select text content that isn't wrapped in an HTML tag with XPath?

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

How do I capture *TARGET* from the following HTML sample with XPath and Puppeteer?

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="sibling_1"> Hello </div>
    <div id="sibling_2"> Good </div>
    TARGET
    <div id="sibling_3"> Bye </div>
</div>
```

I can get *Good Bye* with the following code, but I don't think there is a way to get *TARGET*.

```
let xpath = '//*[@id="sibling_1"]/following-sibling::*';
let elements = await page.$x(xpath);
for(var j in elements){
 let xpathTextContent = await elements[j].getProperty('textContent')
 let text = await xpathTextContent.jsonValue();
 console.log("Text: ",text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in javascript.

```
document.querySelector('div#parent').innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out *TARGET* belongs to the parent element:

```
let xpath = '//*[@id="parent"]';
let elements = await page.$x(xpath);
let xpathTextContent = await elements[0].getProperty('textContent')
let text = await xpathTextContent.jsonValue();
```